# Decodable - inheritance prevents decoder init from synthesizing

Tags: swift, realm, swift4, codable

I have the following Swift 4 `Codable` class, which inherits from Realm's Object type:

```
final class SearchResult: RealmSwift.Object, Codable {
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var region: String = ""

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "name"
        case region = "region"
    }
}
```

The expectation here is that the `init(from decoder: Decoder)` method gets synthesized so that I do not have to implement it myself, which is a huge convenience. However, not implementing this yields the following compiler error:

`super.init isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer`

There are three ways to git rid of the compiler error, but none of them are good:

1. Implement an empty `init(from decoder: Decoder)` method, which just calls `super.init()`. This seems to prevent synthesizing, meaning nothing gets actually decoded, because its just an empty method.
2. Implement the entire `init(from decoder: Decoder)` method by hand. This works, but now the pleasure of using `Codable` is pretty much gone.
3. Remove all Realm-related code. Now Codable works as expected, but, well, now I can't use Realm anymore.

This seems like a Swift bug to me, because it should detect that the `init(from decoder: Decoder)` is in fact being implemented, just not by hand.

Any suggestions or workarounds that I don't know of?

Comment: There's a Swift bug tracking this problem at https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5122. I'd suggest also filing a Radar to let Apple know the pain the workarounds cause, and that you'd value a fix. I'm not sure about workarounds for this issue, though.

Comment: Yep, this is currently a bug. Codable conformance in classes is currently broken in a few places, and I'm looking to fix it soon. (This is an important part of the feature and must be fixed before release.)

Comment: That's good to hear. I guess I'll stick to implementing by hand until then.

Comment: Temp workaround: You could use the EVReflection/Realm subspec to do exactly the same. (Swift 3 compatible, using reflection) https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection/tree/master/Source/Realm You only have to change your Codable to EVReflectable and you can remove the CodingKeys if they are the same, or implement a propertyMapping function if not.

Comment: Same issue with core data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been resolved in Xcode 9 GM, which now allows for initializers to be synthesized by Codable when inheriting from classes with a `required init()` method.